# Reversing leaflet legend values with custom color palette

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet

I'm trying to combine two things that have been discussed a lot StackOverflow:

- How to create a custom colour palette for values above/below zero, and;
- How to reverse the legend in a leafletOutput

I'm almost there, and the colours of the actual polygons themselves are correct, but the legend is not quite correct:
[image]

You can see that if year 2017 is selected from the dropdown, the colour in the hovered over polygon is correct, but the colour scale in the legend isn't.

**The colours should meet at 0 in the legend, but they don't currently.**

I think it's something to do with the reversing, since it's correct if you use the regular palette, but I need the legend to be in descending order.

How can I fix this?

Reproducible code:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(999)

# Read in the countries data for the geometry
countries <- sf::st_read("https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/json/countries.geojson")


# Modify for purposes
countries_mod <- countries %>%
  # Drop actual values
  select(-gdp_md_est, -pop_est) %>%
  # Create random example data
  mutate(
    `2017` = runif(177, -140, 80),
    `2018` = runif(177, -20, 70),
    `2019` = runif(177, -288, 1400)
  ) %>%
  # Pivot into long format for mapping
  pivot_longer(cols = c(`2017`:`2019`))
  


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  selectInput(
    inputId = "year_select",
    label = "Year",
    choices = c("2017", "2018", "2019")
  ),
  
  leafletOutput("plot", height = "500px")
   
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Filter the data by year
  Filtered_dat <- reactive({
    countries_mod %>%
      filter(name == input$year_select)
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(countries) %>%
      addTiles()
  })

  
  observeEvent(Filtered_dat(), {
    
    # Colours for data less than 0 (use abs to get non-negative value)
    colors_negative <- colorRampPalette(c("#fe0000", "#fFc7c7"))(abs(min(Filtered_dat()$value)))
    # Colours for data greater than 0 
    colors_positive <- colorRampPalette(c("#d0f0b7", "#6dfe00"))(max(Filtered_dat()$value))
    
    # Create the palette
    pal <- colorNumeric(c(colors_negative, colors_positive), domain = Filtered_dat()$value)
    
    # Create the reversed palette 
    rev_pal <- colorNumeric(c(colors_negative, colors_positive), domain = Filtered_dat()$value, reverse = TRUE)
    
    leafletProxy("plot") %>%
      setView(0, 0, 1) %>%
      # Remove the old polygons
      clearShapes() %>%
      addPolygons(
        data = Filtered_dat(),
        label = ~value,
        fillColor = ~pal(Filtered_dat()[["value"]]),
        fillOpacity = 1,
        color = "#FEFEFE",
        weight = 1
      ) %>%
      # Remove old legend before redrawing
      clearControls() %>%
      addLegend(
        pal = rev_pal,
        values = Filtered_dat()$value,
        labFormat = labelFormat(transform = function(x) sort(x, decreasing = TRUE))
      )
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

To reverse the color in the legend you can define

```
rev_pal <- colorNumeric(c(colors_negative,colors_positive), domain = rev(Filtered_dat()$value), reverse = TRUE)
```

Then you get

[image: output]

Comment: Still not correct, as you can see in the legend the colours should meet at zero.

Comment: It's still exactly the same as what I posted. The colours in the legend should meet at 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reverse the colors, you should swap the order of your positive and negative vectors of colors and `rev` the colors to get the darker colors as their max and min like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(999)

# Read in the countries data for the geometry
countries <- sf::st_read("https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/json/countries.geojson")


# Modify for purposes
countries_mod <- countries %>%
  # Drop actual values
  select(-gdp_md_est, -pop_est) %>%
  # Create random example data
  mutate(
    `2017` = runif(177, -140, 80),
    `2018` = runif(177, -20, 70),
    `2019` = runif(177, -288, 1400)
  ) %>%
  # Pivot into long format for mapping
  pivot_longer(cols = c(`2017`:`2019`))



ui <- fluidPage(
  
  selectInput(
    inputId = "year_select",
    label = "Year",
    choices = c("2017", "2018", "2019")
  ),
  
  leafletOutput("plot", height = "500px")
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Filter the data by year
  Filtered_dat <- reactive({
    countries_mod %>%
      filter(name == input$year_select)
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(countries) %>%
      addTiles()
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(Filtered_dat(), {
    
    # Colours for data less than 0 (use abs to get non-negative value)
    colors_negative <- colorRampPalette(c("#fe0000", "#fFc7c7"))(abs(min(Filtered_dat()$value)))
    # Colours for data greater than 0 
    colors_positive <- colorRampPalette(c("#d0f0b7", "#6dfe00"))(max(Filtered_dat()$value))
    
    # Create the palette
    pal <- colorNumeric(c(rev(colors_positive), rev(colors_negative)), domain = Filtered_dat()$value)
    
    # Create the reversed palette 
    rev_pal <- colorNumeric(c(rev(colors_positive), rev(colors_negative)), domain = Filtered_dat()$value, reverse = TRUE)
    
    leafletProxy("plot") %>%
      setView(0, 0, 1) %>%
      # Remove the old polygons
      clearShapes() %>%
      addPolygons(
        data = Filtered_dat(),
        label = ~value,
        fillColor = ~pal(Filtered_dat()[["value"]]),
        fillOpacity = 1,
        color = "#FEFEFE",
        weight = 1
      ) %>%
      # Remove old legend before redrawing
      clearControls() %>%
      addLegend(
        pal = rev_pal,
        values = Filtered_dat()$value,
        labFormat = labelFormat(transform = function(x) sort(x, decreasing = TRUE))
      )
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Not correct; the colours should meet at zero, and in your solution they're also upside down.